# File upload button is not working

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want file upload in bootstrap,it is working only on chrome not in firefox ,i want work for both browser,if  anyone can fix problem also ok,otherwise give me the link for bootstrap fileupload,i searched i can't get ,i tried this one but i don't know how to insert the value this one little bit difficult for any one know means tell me http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal">
    Launch Form Modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="formModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="formModalLabel">Large Modal Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form form action="original_photo_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" style="margin-top: 20px;">

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">File Upload</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                                        <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                                                            <div class="input-append">
                                                                <div class="uneditable-input">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-file fileupload-exists"></i>
                                                                    <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                                                    <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                                                                    <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
                                                                    <input type="file" name="file" required>

                                                                </span>
                                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-8">
                                                        <button type="submit" value="register" class="btn btn-primary" id='btn-submit'>Upload The Photo</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens in firefox? In what way does it not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: While uploading file not working,not clickable that button

Answer (score 2):

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`for the form to use upload feature.

```
<form id="demo-form" class="form-horizontal mb-lg" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: still now not working,not clickable in firefox but chrome is working